# Onvif java or javacv recording video to file from RTSP?

Tags: java, opencv, rtsp, javacv

From the camera direct streaming is possible and can display it as well, but not write to a video  file any format will do. But from rtsp we get frames by frames and i would like to develop without any more external librarys apart from opencv or javacv if possible. 
and in opencv-java  videoWriter is missing([here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3453)) so unable to capture video to a file.

In javacv was unable to create a stream or a recorder from rtsp.
case:

> FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("rtsp://1ink...");
>   FrameRecorder fr = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("rtsp://linkf", 0);

Error is :

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniavcodec in java.library.path
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
>       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
>       at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:535)
>       at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:410)
>       at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
>       at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec.(avcodec.java:12)
>       at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:103)

in both case
The rtsp link is working as i get photos from the camera.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why negative vote? If there is a solution do mention or if its a duplicate question do mention i didnt find any duplicate. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. If any one will be helpfull with it.

In javacv if any one has the following error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniavcodec in java.library.path

do add

> Class.forName("org.bytedeco.javacpp.swresample");

Rest will work fine. All the best.